# run Spring Boot using Java -jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that is working property, however I want to run it on one of my servers using the "java -jar" command

I did read this

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html

which says I can run the application by

```
$ java -jar target/myapplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

However I don't see a jar file under the target folder.

Any thoughts on how I can run this by using the java -jar command?

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.plivo/plivo-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.plivo</groupId>
            <artifactId>plivo-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you `clean install` the project?

Comment: I did clean it by going to Project -> Clean, but I don't see an option for clean install

Comment: I guess you are using Eclipse IDE to clean the project. I suggest to go to the command line tool (`cmd` on Windows, `Terminal` on Linux); `cd` to your project's root directory (where `pom.xml`resides). Then run `mvn clean install`. This will generate `jar` in `target` directory which can be run using `java -jar`.

Comment: please post your `pom.xml`

Comment: yes share pom.xml

Comment: @OnkarKamatkar I'm using Spring Tools Suit. I will try your suggestion

Comment: @spandey15 added

Comment: <packaging>war</packaging> change to jar

Comment: I changed it to jar and ran `mvn clean install` and it did generate the jar file in the target folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the Clean install from Your Maven or Gradle Build . Not from Your Eclipse Clean Build.

If You do the the clean from your eclipse It will recompile all your Project.

If You do the clean insatll for your Maven(right click the pom.xml file  and do the clean install ) then it will generate jar or war file to target folder